# Split An Array into sub arrays that each sub array sum value not exceed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I would like to create sub arrays of **[10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,4,4,4]** that sum of each sub array is **not** greater than 100, so the result should be **[[10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,4,4],[4]]**

I tried below, but not work not sure where the problem is at

```
   const arr=[10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,4,4,4]

  
    const result=[]

    let sum=0
    let temp=[]

    for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
      if(sum+arr[i]<=100){
        sum+=arr[i]
        temp.push(arr[i])
      }else{
         result.push(temp)
         sum=0
         temp.length=0

         temp.push(arr[i])
         sum+=arr[i]
      }
    }

console.log(result) //[ [ 4 ] ]
```

Comment: Change `temp.length=0` to `temp = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you push `temp` onto `result` you need to create a new `temp` array, not set the length of the old array to `0`, because you have a reference to that array in `result`. So change `temp.length = 0` to `temp = []`.

And at the end of the loop you need to push the final `temp` onto `result`.

```js
const arr = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 4, 4, 4]
const result = []

let sum = 0
let temp = []

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (sum + arr[i] <= 100) {
    sum += arr[i]
    temp.push(arr[i])
  } else {
    result.push(temp)
    sum = 0
    temp = []

    temp.push(arr[i])
    sum += arr[i]
  }
}

if (temp.length > 0) {
  result.push(temp);
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First: don't use `temp.length=0`

Second: you're not creating a new array inside `else`, so basically you're editing what you have pushed inside `result`

Inside `else`, after pushing into `result`, just use `temp = []`

On top of that, you shall check if there are additional items inside `temp` and the end of the loop, and do one more push into `result`